Question on the geometric lemma in $p$-adic classical groups
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL} \DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp} \DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}\DeclareMathOperator\B{B} $My question is about the geometric lemma of $p$-adic classical groups not $\GL_n$. For $\GL_n$, Kenta Suzuki gave a very nice answer! (See Jacquet module of irreducible principal series.)
Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field and $\Sp_{2n}$ the symplectic group over a $2n$-dimensional symplectic space over $F$. Let $B_n$ be $p$-adic group defined over $F$. Let $\B_n$ be the borel subgroup of $\GL_n$.
Let $\chi=\chi_1\otimes \dotsb \otimes \chi_n$ be a character of $B_n(F)$ and consider $\pi=\Ind_{B_n(F)}^{\Sp_{2n}(F)} \chi$, the normalized induced representation from $\chi$ to $\Sp_{2n}(F)$.
For $1\le a \le n$, let $P_a$ be the parabolic subgroup of $\Sp_{2n}(F)$ whose Levi subgroup is isomorphic to $\GL_a(F) \times \Sp_{2(n-a)}(F)$.
Let $J_{P_a}$ be the normalized Jacquet funtor. Let $$S_{n,a}=\{s\in S_n|s^{-1}(1)<\dotsb <s^{-1}(a),s^{-1}(a+1)<\cdots<s^{-1}(n)\}$$ be the subset of the symmetric group $S_n$ of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$
Then I am wondering whether the geometric lemma tells that $J_{P_a}(\pi)$ is equal to $\bigoplus_{s\in S_{n,a}}\Ind_{\B_a}^{\GL_a}(\chi_{s(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes \chi_{s(a)}) \boxtimes \Ind_{B_{2n-2a}}^{\Sp_{2n-2a}}(\chi_{s(a+1)}\otimes \dotsb \otimes \chi_{s(n)})$, up to semisimplication.
As is well known, in the Weyl group of $\Sp(2n)$, there are involutive elements $e_i$ such that $e_i^2=1$. (i.e. it changes $t_i$ and $t_i^{-1}$ in the diagonal elements of the maximal split torus.) However, such $e_i$ seems not an element $W^{M,N}$ in the Berstein and Zelvinski’s paper Induced representations of reductive $\mathfrak p$-adic groups. I page 448. (Here, $M$ is the maximal split torus and $N$ is the Levi of $P_a$.)
Is this right?
Any comments are appreciated!

What is the end of the sentence "I read"? Was the sentence ending "the subset of the symmetric group" (that originally had no period) supposed to continue further? Did you mean that the $e_i$ are idempotent or (as you wrote) involutive? // MathJax note: since MathJax is less aggressive about eating whitespace than TeX, when you start your post with a "preamble", you must put the first character of the post right next to the $ that ends the preamble block, or else your post will start with blank space (in your case, blank lines). I edited accordingly.

@LSpice, Thank you for your interest to my question and very kind comment for the use of MO. I will remember your caution for further post. For your questions, let me answer. Symmetric group I mean is $S_n$m the symmetric group of ${1,2,\cdots,n}$. The letter 'I read' should be omitted! $e_i$ is the element of the Weyl group of $Sp(2n)$ changing $t_i$ and $t_i^{-1}$ in the diagonal element.
